# Filter magento order collection

Tags: magento

I use the following line to load collection of orders from magento:

```
// Load Order Collection
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```

How do you filter this collection to ignore orders with status "canceled" and "complete"?

---

**Update**

After posting this, I was bored so I did some digging around and this post helped me find the right lines of code: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/201797/#t287235

This is how I solved it:

```
// Load Order Collection
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled','complete')));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `addFieldToFilter` method

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled','complete')));
```

Comment: 'nin' stands for 'not in' by the way. you can find a list of filters in the following class: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php - Check the comment for '_getConditionSql'.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the original definitions:

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('nin' => array(
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW,
        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED
            )));
```

Like defined in Mage_Sales_Model_Order:

```
/**
 * Order states
 */
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_COMPLETE        = 'complete';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
```