# get order status from order id, email and customer's last name

Tags: magento

I'm currently looking for a method from which I can get the order status based on the `order id`, `customer email` and `customer last name`.

I'd written this code so far

```
public function orderHistoryAction(){
    $req = $this->getRequest();
    $oid = $req->getParam('oid', '');
    $lnm = $req->getParam('lnm', '');
    $eml = $req->getParam('eml', '');

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($oid);
    if ($order->getId()) {
        if ((strcasecmp($lnm, $order->getCustomerLastname()) == 0) && (strcasecmp($eml, $order->getCustomerEmail()) == 0)) {
            echo $order->getStatusLabel();
        } else {
            echo 'invalid';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}
```

and is working well for both *customer* and *guest*. But this doesn't seems to me the right approach. I supposed to used something like written in [this blog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part12-series-collection-sql-operations) or [here too](http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/collection-and-sql-operations.html). If anybody could make me correct?

Comment: You can obviously make a new module to get order status from order id, email and customer's last name. Use an Observer in your module for the same.

Comment: isn't it be a overhead to store info in my module them display the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use collections, the code you need will look like:

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', array('eq' => $oid))
->addFieldToFilter('customer_lastname', array('eq' => $lnm))
->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('eq' => $eml));

if ($order_collection->getSize() > 0) {
    $order = $order_collection->getFirstItem();
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

You can find another answer here: [Filter magento order collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524390/filter-magento-order-collection)